# Loading multiple images from file path and assigning them to image control inside collection view sometimes does not load properly

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

There are around 30-40 images that gets downloaded from the server and saved to local and then file path is passed through which image source is generated. Download call is made whenever user scrolls the collectionview. Sometimes images are getting loaded completely and sometime partially.

```
                    <CollectionView 
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 </CollectionView>
```

C#

```
   await Utility.FileHanler.Download(Id, resourceTypeId, material, ThumbURL, token, (arg) =>
                            {
                                
                                LoadImage(arg);
                            });


  public async Task Download(int id, int resourceType,string fileName,string thumbnailUrl, CancellationToken token , Action<string> CompletionHandler)
    {
        string destinationFolder;
        
        destinationFolder = Path.Combine(FileHandler.Images, id.ToString());
        
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder);
            }
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(thumbnailUrl + App.Token);
            WebResponse ws = await wr.GetResponseAsync();
            Stream s = ws.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            var filePath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName);
            var dlStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            int readBytes = s.Read(buffer, 0, 10240);
            while (readBytes > 0)
            {
                dlStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                readBytes = s.Read(buffer, 0, 10240);
            }
            dlStream.Close();
            dlStream.Dispose();
            s.Close();
            s.Dispose();
            ws.Close();
            CompletionHandler?.Invoke(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    public void LoadImage(string filePath)
    {
          Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
          {
           Image = ImageSource.FromFile(filePath);
          });
    }
```

[image: CLipped Image]

[image: Image Loaded fully]

Comment: Can you please check if the image has been downloaded completely? And also you can bind the remote url to the image source directly and it will download the image automaticalluy.

Comment: Yes once the image gets downloaded then only i assign the path. I can't use the url directly i need to get that work offilne also @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Xamarin.forms? I would recommend you not to download the  30-40 images at the same time.

Comment: I am using Xamarin forms version 4.8.0.1821. I am not dowloading 30-40 at same time. they are like 15-20 at at time as they are loaded on scroll.

Comment: Does this issue happen if you load 5 photos one time?

Comment: This is weird! Sometimes it is happening for loading 5-6 images during scroll and sometimes it is not happening for 10 images . This is only occurring while downloading images from server. once they are downloaded and i restart app it fetches from local and it works fine @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: Are you updating the Image property until the image has been downloaded completely?

Comment: I have added more code here, Please take a look at it! Once the completion handler is invoked then I load the image from local. And Completion handler is invoked once image is downloaded. @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: While the codes looks fine. This may caused by the rendering of collectionview. Are you testing in both iOS and Android? Is this happen in both platforms?

Comment: I am working only on android. So didn't check  on ios! @JackHua-MSFT